# easy way to subset data into bins

Tags: r, subset, bins

I have a data frame as seen below with over 1000 rows. I would like to subset the data into bins by 1m intervals (0-1m, 1-2m, etc.). Is there an easy way to do this without finding the minimum depth and using the subset command multiple times to place the data into the appropriate bins?

```
Temp..ºC. Depth..m. Light  time       date
1     17.31     -14.8   255 09:08 2012-06-19
2     16.83     -21.5   255 09:13 2012-06-19
3     17.15     -20.2   255 09:17 2012-06-19
4     17.31     -18.8   255 09:22 2012-06-19
5     17.78     -13.4   255 09:27 2012-06-19
6     17.78      -5.4   255 09:32 2012-06-19
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the name of your data frame is `df`, do the following:

```
split(df, findInterval(df$Depth..m., floor(min(df$Depth..m.)):0))
```

You will then get a list where each element is a data frame containing the rows that have `Depth..m.` within a particular 1 m interval.

Notice however that empty bins will be removed. If you want to keep them you can use `cut` instead of `findInterval`. The reason is that `findInterval` returns an integer vector, making it impossible for `split` to know what the set of valid bins is. It only knows the values it has seen and discards the rest. `cut` on the other hand returns a factor, which has all valid bins defined as levels.